# Writing dynamic web elements to XLSX using Apache POI-Selenium web driver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, xpath, dynamic

Hi I am working on Selenium Webdriver, I have web site with a drop down and have to select drop down value then click a a button to load entire page. Once page loads then have to find a text from web page using xpath. I want to write the drop down text into xlx file and also I want to write text (found out from xpath) into xlx. Both of these values are dynamic. How to start on this, any code can help me.
Without using maven and selenium I want to write data to excel file
Below is the screen shot of the elements i want to write into excel file

[image: Site]

I have written to get the drop down values and xpath text-
Want to write **StockScrip** and **Pattern** into excel file

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import ExcelData.BullishBearishExcelFile;

public class Driver {
public static  WebDriver driver;
public  static  void main(String[] args) {
BullishBearishExcelFile data = new BullishBearishExcelFile();
driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.icharts.in");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@src='http://www.icharts.in/StockGlance.png']")).click();
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement webelescripDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("symbol"));
Select stockName= new Select(webelescripDropDown);
List<WebElement> stocks = stockName.getOptions();
int stockCount = stocks.size(); 
for(int j=1;j<=stockCount;j++){
webelescripDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("symbol"));
stockName= new Select(webelescripDropDown);
stockName.selectByIndex(j);
String stockScrip = stockName.getOptions().get(j).getText();
System.out.println(stockScrip+"=stockname clicked");
driver.findElement(By.id("action")).click();
WebElement pattern = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Short  Term (5 days) :')]"));
String bullishPattern = pattern.getText();
System.out.println("Pattern is ="+bullishPattern);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Had tried something similar long back, did it using Apache POI lib, you can also use JExcel but as far as i know it has few limitations.

find the scenario at my site : [mylearnings.net](http://mylearnings.net/SeleniumJavaAPIs.html#/6/3)

Adding same content here for completeness:

Scenario:

- Consider an Excel file having a sheet with columns like, scriptname, CostPrice, Quantity, Price , Valuation(Price*Quantity), Profit(Valuation-(CostPrice*Quantity)).
- there was need to update Price cell every day for different stocks and Valuation and Profit gets calculated based on that.
- Following is code for this scenario. Even if you don't get scenario, code is updated with comments so you will get idea about how to use different functions of HSSF API.

  ```
  public static void writeToExcelHSSF(String filename)
  {
  try{
      //Create a workbook, as here we are trying to modify an Existing file need to provide FileInputStream as argument               
      HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(path + xlsFile));

      //FileOutputStream will be needed while writing changes back to a xls file
      FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path + "final1.xls");

      //Get sheet by providing index of the sheet
      HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

      //Creating a evaluator, it will be used to evaluate formula of a cell
      HSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(wb); 

      //Get numder of rows of a sheet 
      int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
      System.out.println("Sheet " + wb.getNumberOfSheets() + " \"" + wb.getSheetName(0) + "\" has " + rows    + " row(s).");

      //Create a row object;
      HSSFRow row;

      //Different cell objects
      HSSFCell scriptCell;
      HSSFCell priceCell;
      HSSFCell valuationCell;
      HSSFCell profitCell;
      String scriptName;

      for(int k=1;k< rows;k++){

                  //get row based on index(row number)    
                  row = sheet.getRow(k);

                  //get particular cell of a row                  
                  scriptCell = row.getCell(9);

                  //get string value from the cell
                  scriptName =scriptCell.getStringCellValue();

                  priceCell =row.getCell(5);
                  valuationCell =row.getCell(6);
                  profitCell =row.getCell(7);

                  //set value in a cell, (here parseStocks is just a user defined function to fetch value of a stock)
                  priceCell.setCellValue(parseStocks(path + filename,scriptName));

                  //Trigger cache clearance, so evaluation of formula on this cell is done with latest value
                  evaluator.notifyUpdateCell(priceCell);

                  //Re-evaluate formula of a cell
                  evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(valuationCell);
                  evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(profitCell);
      }

      //writing back workbook to output stream
      wb.write(stream);
      stream.close();
  }
  catch( IOException e)
  {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }   
  }
  ```

Don't forget to add apache POI library to your build path.
link: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

Comment: Hi Kavan, Thanks for quick reply. I want to create a fresh file first and push dynamic data from drop down and xpath text to excel file. That is my first object. Updating sheet will be done later.The data which I would like to push to

Comment: hmm, i will leave it up to you to figure out. go through Apache POI documentation.